# Vert.x: Blocking handler issue

Tags: vert.x

I want to use blocking handler, but still get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response has already been written
```

Here is my code:

**Server.java**

```
r.route("/api/details/send/").handler(BodyHandler.create());
r.route("/api/details/send/").handler(ctx-> {
JsonArray ja = ctx.getBodyAsJsonArray();
JsonArray params = new JsonArray();
vertx.executeBlocking(futur -> {
      for(int i =0; i<ja.size();i++) {
          JsonObject req = new JsonObject();
          req.put("QUERY", "INSERT INTO detailsfacture VALUES ('',?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
          req.put("DB", "MYSQL_");
          params.add(ja.getJsonObject(i).getValue("typefacture"))
                .add(ja.getJsonObject(i).getValue("activites"))
                .add(Integer.parseInt(ja.getJsonObject(i).getValue("qte").toString()))
                .add(Double.parseDouble(ja.getJsonObject(i).getValue("pu").toString())
                .add(ja.getJsonObject(i).getValue("unite"))
                .add(Double.parseDouble(ja.getJsonObject(i).getValue("montant").toString())
                .add(ja.getJsonObject(i).getValue("codefacture"));
          req.put("PARAMS", params);
          eb.send("EXECUTE", req, res -> {
              if (res.succeeded()) {
                  params.clear();
                  ctx.response().putHeader("content-type", "application/json").end(res.result().body().toString());
              } else {
                  ctx.response().putHeader("content-type", "application/json").end(res.cause().getMessage());
              }

          });

      }
      String result = "orsys";
      futur.complete(result);

  },resultat->{
     ctx.response().putHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain");
     //resultat.result().toString();
  });
});
```

**MySql.java**

```
eb.consumer("MYSQL_EXECUTE_WITH_PARAMS", req->{
  try{
      JsonObject reqParams = (JsonObject)req.body();
      String sql = reqParams.getString("QUERY");
      client.getConnection( connection -> {
          if (connection.succeeded()) {
              try{
                  SQLConnection con = connection.result();
                  con.updateWithParams(sql,reqParams.getJsonArray("PARAMS"), query -> {
                      if(query.succeeded()){
                          UpdateResult urs = query.result();
                          req.reply(urs.toJson());
                          //req.reply(query.result());
                      }else{
                          req.fail(24, "Err Request : "+query.cause().getMessage());
                      }
                  });
              }catch(Exception e){
                  req.fail(24,  "Err Conn Failed : "+e.getMessage());
              }
          } else {
              req.fail(24,  "Err No Connection : "+connection.cause().getMessage());
          }
      });
  }catch(Exception e){
      req.fail(24, e.getMessage());
  }
});
```

P.S. : When I remove executeBlocking only the first records is registred in my database.
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried another solution to get my query like that (?,?,...,?),(?,?,...,?),..,(?,?,...,?).

Here is my code :

```
public static String getMultipleInsertReq(String table, JsonArray columns,JsonArray data){
JsonObject tab= Tables.Tables_list.getJsonObject(table); // name of table
String sql = "";
if(tab != null){
        sql = "INSERT INTO "+table + "( ";
        if(columns == null){
            columns = tab.getJsonArray("COLS"); //columns from ur database
        }
        if(columns!=null){
            for(int i=0;i<columns.size();i++){
                if(i==columns.size()-1){
                    sql+=columns.getString(i)+") VALUES";
                }
                else{
                    sql+=columns.getString(i)+",";
                }
            }
            for(int i =0; i<data.size();i++){
                for(int j=0; j<columns.size();j++){
                    if(j==columns.size()-1 && i!=data.size()-1){
                        sql+="?),";
                    }
                    else if (i==data.size()-1 && j==columns.size()-1){
                        sql+="?)";
                    }
                    else if (j==0){
                        sql+="(?,";
                    }
                    else{
                        sql+="?,";
                    }
                }
            }
            return sql;
        }
    }
    return  null;
}
```

Hope it helps.
P.S.: it's only a query builder so you can adapt it depending on your needs.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You insert entities into `detailsfacture` in a loop. For each insert you call following:

```
ctx.response().putHeader("content-type", "application/json").end(res.result().body().toString());
```

As you can see you call the `end(...)` method of the response object. Thats where the `IllegalStateException` comes from. As the [documentation](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/http/HttpServerResponse.html#end--) states:

```
Once the response has ended, it cannot be used any more.
```

So you problem has nothing to do with the `executeBlocking`.

You should take a look at the [`write(...)`](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/http/HttpServerResponse.html#write-java.lang.String-) method of `HttpServerResponse`. For each insert you should call `write(...)` instead of `end(...)`. But this will only work if you know the complete length of the whole response because you need to set the header `Content-length`. If you are finished with all inserts you need to call `end()` to complete the response. Also you should only set the header once and not for each insert.

Now some additional comments. I don't see the need for `executeBlocking` in your case. Because of the problem with `Content-length` I recommend to wrap each insert with a `Future` and compose all of them with `CompositeFuture`. The `Future` `futur` is used the wrong way. The `send(...)` method of Event bus is not blocking and asynchronous. So the `futur.complete(result)` is called right after you send all your inserts. Also it's strange that the `consumer` consumes `MYSQL_EXECUTE_WITH_PARAMS` and the `send` sends to `EXECUTE`.

Comment: Thank you @alexvetter for your answer, I changed end to write and I removed putHeader inside the loop but still got an error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must set the Content-Length header to be the total size of the message body BEFORE sending any data if you are not using HTTP chunked encoding.
And I still have only one record into my database.

Comment: I see, as long as you don't know the complete length of your response this could be a problem. That's why I would create a `Future` for each insert and compose them together. In the handler of the composed `Future` you could use `end(...)` because you would already have the whole response.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should use Future for each insert because I it's dynamic ( data comes from a grid ). And honestly I just begin with this and I didn't find examples for future and eventbus. So my question is in case I should use Future where I have to make my future before eb or before the loop for ? Regards.

Comment: As far as I understand your code you need a `Future` for each insert. And yes that's possible – even with dynamic data. After the loop you need to compose the list of `Futures` with the `CompositeFuture`.

Comment: Again, not a problem of `executeBlocking`. It's more a problem about understanding handling asynchronous results.